# How long should I cook apples in the oven?

Tags: oven, apples, apple-pie

How long do I need to cook fresh apples (sliced) in the oven (at 350 degrees) to get a good apple pie consistency?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are asking this? The temperature and time is usually dependent on the preparation of the pie itself and is recipe specific. Some apple pie uses a dry filling that produces liquid as it bakes while other recipe start out with some liquid base with the apples. The time that the recipe you are using gives should be what you should be using.

Answer (score 3):

Various factors influence the consistency of an apple when it bakes.

- Acidity. The more acidic the apple is, the better will the apple preserve its pectin and remain its crunch. Also any acidic fluids surrounding the apple will make an impact here.
- Thickness of the slices. Thin slices will make the apple heat up faster.
- The surrounding environments ability to transfer heat. If the apples are surrounded by a watery liquid heat will be transferred much more quickly to the apple than if it was surrounded by air. Other kinds of liquids will transfer heat quicker or slower.

So you see there are no hard and fast answers. But knowledge of these factors might help you build up experience to make a qualified guess in each case.

Comment: And when you lack the knowledge in the beginning, JDWRS (just do what the recipe says). I just made that up, don't judge. :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: between 15 and 45 minutes, depending on the thickness of your apples. Check them periodically, when they’re fork tender, they’re probably cooked enough.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on a lot of things, as Jay said in his comment, not just the preparation of the pie (its depth, the amount of liquid/goop, whether it's covered) but also personal preferences, and the crispness of the apples you've decided to use.

Use a recipe as a guideline, and then check it periodically as it approaches the end time. If the apples aren't cooked enough for you and the crust is starting to brown, you can cover it loosely with foil to protect it. Remember what worked for the next time, and you should be set.

Comment: Also note that the doneness of the apple isn't the only thing you need to check. For many pies, the apple can be the correct texture while the thickness of the liquid is still too thin. One of the most common mistakes first time apple pie bakers make is baking watery apple pie. The juices need extra time to reduce into it's gooey goodness. And last thing I forgot to mention is you need to choose apples that can withstand this type of baking. Granny smith and Honey Crisp are two great choices to choose from. (@Jefromi, you may cannibalize this comment into your post if you want).